# Create a clock but not in a new window but in the programme itself

Tags: python

Is it possible to create a clock on Python programme that would keep updating but not appear on new window?

Cause, I try finding on Google but many results is to create digital clock on a new window instead,

Desired outcome:

```
23:59
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
import os
import datetime
import time

#function to clear the screen
def cls():
    os.system('cls' if os.name=='nt' else 'clear')

 


while True:
    cls()
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    print (now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
    time.sleep(1)
```

The above code snippet would do nicely. This approach, however, is less "creating a clock" and more "display the computer's time value"